Confluence connection to Copilot within Teams
Does anyone is using copilot within teams and implemented the confluence-cloud connection? The last integration i have made was the jira <-> copilot integration which worked pretty smooth. Therefore i just need to toggle the button for the jira integration and a pop-up was shown where i need to login:

Now I tried to connect our copilot with confluence cloud as a information-backbone. I did exactly the similar things as for JIRA.
But for confluence cloud it shows "login required" but i can not get any login-pop-up information. Any ideas how i can connect the teams copilot to confluence?

